# Get rid of debian-sys-maint instead of root in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql8

We've recently upgraded from MySQL Percona 5.7 to 8 and we're in the phase of transitioning from `mysql_native_password` to `caching_sha2_password`.

As far as I understand, the only way to upgrade the `Plugin` is with the below query, and if no password is supplied, an empty one will.

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
```

The two questions I have are the following.

However prior any changes, is the `debian-sys-maint` still relevant in Stretch - MySQL 8 ? What would it imply to remove that account ? Considering that `root` has replaced it over the years, and on a fresh new install on another Stretch, it doesn't exist anymore.

Similar situation with the mysql.session that didn't migrate to `caching_sha2_password` during the upgrade, would it be fine to change his plugin without setting any password ?

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host      | User          | plugin                | authentication_string                     |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | mysql.session | mysql_native_password | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as the root MySQL account uses `unix_auth`authentication plugin (so no password required for root user to log into MySQL) then you should be fine to remove the `debian-sys-maint` user.

Note that as of Debian 9/Stretch by default, it no longer exists of you install MariaDB from the default repos.

If you don't have `unix_auth`authentication enabled for the root user, it may still work ok, although some automated functionality may no longer work.